# Does Dirichlet function contradicts the Lusin's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Lusin's theorem states that **an almost-everywhere finite function is measurable** if and only if it is a **continuous function on nearly all its domain**. However, Dirichlet function seems to be a counterexample.

The dirichlet function on the interval $[0,1]$ is defined as $D(x)=\left\{\begin{align}&0,x\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\\&1,x\in\mathbb [0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q\end{align}\right.$. Since both $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ and $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ are measurable, $D(x)$ is **measurable**.

However, it is well-known that $D(x)$ is **nowhere continuous** on $[0,1]$. I wonder where such a paradox comes from.

Comment: I think there must be some common mistakes for beginners in real analysis, though I cannot figure it out right now.

Comment: The irrationals are nearly all of its domain. And restricted to the irrationals it's continuous.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Get it, but how to define "continuous" when its domain contains no intervals?

Comment: *it is a continuous function on nearly all its domain* --- Should be "it has a continuous restriction defined on nearly all of its domain". I don't know whether the following will help, but see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61284/13130).

Comment: In my post, the definition of Lusin's theorem is taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem). In fact the word a.e. (abbreviation of almost everywhere) is universally adapted in real analysis, e.g. "continuous a.e." means the discontinuity is zero-measured. From my perspetive, Lusin's theorem reveals that $D(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, rather than $m(\mathbb R\setminus\{x:w_D(x)=0\})=0$.

Comment: Continuity has nothing to do with intervals. The irrationals inherit a topology from the reals, and continuity means the inverse image of an open set is open.

Comment: This question is answered here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23372/lusins-theorem